# IMFMediaSession.Close() not working as intended?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-imfmediasession-close , once the IMFMediaSession.Close is called, i am supposed to receive an event called MESessionClosed, which i am not getting always, but in most cases.

I got a few customers with growing native memory leaks, and i think that one of the reasons is either what i mentioned above, or MediaFoundation interaction with the GPU driver, since i have analyzed dumps where i saw thousands of threads open in atiumd64.dll, method OpenAdapter:

```
00 000000b0`cecff8f8 00007ff8`c1cf9252 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x14
01 000000b0`cecff900 00007ff8`752d2ccd KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xa2
02 000000b0`cecff9a0 00007ff8`757bf247 atiumd64!OpenAdapter+0x63ced
03 000000b0`cecff9d0 00007ff8`757bf3ee 
atiumd64!XdxInitXopAdapterServices+0x3d0a57
04 000000b0`cecffa00 00007ff8`c4293034 
atiumd64!XdxInitXopAdapterServices+0x3d0bfe
05 000000b0`cecffa30 00007ff8`c4d91461 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
06 000000b0`cecffa60 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

I had a total of 160000 topologies created over the span of 4 days, and some 100 did not raise the MESessionClosed at all, and i fear these are the ones which cause a leak.

In cases where no MESessionClosed is sent, i notice that they all have one error in common: -1072870850, which is MF_E_SAMPLEALLOCATOR_EMPTY.

I would love to know if anyone has had experience with MediaFoundation not raising MESessionClosed according to documentation.

Comment: What are the source/sink/transform used in the topology ?

Comment: @mofo77 we have a custom implementation of IMFMediaSource. we also have a proprietary container we call FrameCache, this is what our custom IMFMediaSource is using. sink is an hwnd of a wpf control (inherits HwndHost). we have a custom mft that we put in the topology for decoding, and a color converter after that.

Comment: Seems to be memory leak issue, you'd better to use smart point Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr to hold every MF pointers/objects to manage the reference count, and make sure every pointer/object to be released after calling IMFMediaSession::Close

Comment: @ravin.wang i reduced the topology to a minimum, there are no negative HRs, or missing release calls :/ seems like the c# version of a simple topology leaks, while the same topology in c++ does not.

Comment: In case someones ever falls on MF_E_SAMPLEALLOCATOR_EMPTY... In my case, it was just because I forgot to call MFStartup(MF_VERSION), yeah I know I'm a bonehead. Everything was working, but I guess MFStartup runs some frame pump somewhere and if it's not started, an allocator somewhere runs of samples pretty quickly (like 10 samples and get MF_E_SAMPLEALLOCATOR_EMPTY)

Answer (score 1):

`MESessionClosed` event is created as a result of completion of asynchronously executed `IMFMediaSession::Close` call. Your not getting indicates a closing problem, perhaps a problem with one of the primitives participating in the topology, such as for example, failure to end streaming because of outstanding or leaked reference on some object.

Given the description of the problem perhaps the best way to address the problem is to attach debugger to the process (live or creating a dump and reviewing it interactively) expecting to find a thread waiting for something to close or complete.

Your seeing `MF_E_SAMPLEALLOCATOR_EMPTY` earlier might suggest that a leaked pointer to one of the samples prevents from terminating a sample allocator inside one of the primitives, which in turn create a deadlock.

Other than this you might want to do mftrace on the process and compare output produced by closed session to the other one that fails.

One thing you are also interested in, including putting it as a part of the question, is understanding the topology and especially whether it has third party or optional segments you can temporarily exclude. Since you cannot do much of debugging of MF internals directly, your options to change the topology could help you narrow the scope of the issue to specific primitive which is giving you the trouble. If the topology has your own primitives, you are interested in reviewing their termination behavior.

Comment: i saw many dumps, none show me a callstack that contains anything that i wrote, its always combase/evr/gpu-driver. sometimes only RAM explodes, sometimes both RAM and handles/threads go to heavens before crash. i started logging every topology step, and only thing i realized was the occasional MESessionClosed event missing. so it sounds like we gotta take a look at our custom IMFMediaSource/MFT/FrameCache(frame container, used by our custom IMFMediaSource) in hope to see why closing sometimes doesnt work. maybe the leak will go away once this works. gonna try with mftrace first i guess

Comment: It might be not so easy to troubleshoot it, but if you have your own primitives in the pipeline chances are high that they are not responding well to closing requests. Not seeing anything on call stack is making it less obvious but there should still be something you can register: unhandled outstanding request etc.

Comment: You have custom pipeline, difficult to help. It is not because you have few customers with the problem, that your code is not buggy. You talk about wpf control, which adds difficulty, i think. The only time I saw memory leaks from mediafoundation, was when using media session and video capture, a known bug under windows 7.

Comment: yeah, im aware im not going to get perfect answers... the custom pipeline doesnt quite help :b but im merely looking for ideas what would make sense to do next to find the error.

Comment: In your case, use trace/log strategy in your code. Check with log that all your components close succefully. Also for example, when you release an objet, you can check some things like this : ULONG ulTest = m_pSession->Release(); assert(ulTest == 0); sometimes you know that ulTest must be 0, check it at the right place.

Comment: i replaced our custom components, and now i have just an mp4 file, some default microsoft h264 decoder, default EVR, no custom IMFMediaSource... the leak still happens. i feel that the problem is that im giving mediafoundation some task for which it needs 15 secs to execute, and im doing this every 10 seconds, so the memory/handles/threads keep going up and at some point the computer is just overloaded and cant do anything anymore... this stress test is 9 video slots, in which i display the 720p mp4 file, and these 9 slots are being reloaded(delete old topology, create new one) every 10 secs.

Comment: everything works fine for like 2-3 minutes, and then it doesnt even render frames on my video slots, but memory/handles/threads keeps going up. do you know if its legitimate to call Shutdown on IMFMediaSession, even without receiving MESessionClosed first? because thats what this code currently does... if there is no MESessionClosed for 10 secs after calling Close, we call Shutdown on anyway. i also have mftrace with log level 16 of a working topology, and of a non working topology, if someone feels like throwing a look, i could share them...

Comment: I'd say `Shutdown` is a legit call at any time. It disassembles the internals with assumption that any trailing calls would be bounced with `MF_E_SHUTDOWN` error. However it's always better to do termination gracefully, so no wonder if something crashes in case of early shutdown. I'd say it's worth trying out. Also even though it's more or less clear what you are trying to do, it's hard to follow without code, without demo example. I am afraid you are on your own with such testing.

Comment: there are 4000 rows of code in our player. i gotta find a way to isolate the error in a simple program. i might also find the error by doing that. ill come annoy you a bit more if i get something debug-able. thankies

Comment: ok, indeed, isolating the code can make it possible to find errors .

Comment: been debugging alot, ended up creating a winforms application with the simplest topology i can imagine, and i still have the problem that sometimes MESessionClosed doesnt come. i am using mfnet library, the managed c# wrapper of mediafoundation (http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/). i will debug on my private machine to see how it looks when i have a better GPU/CPU. is it safe to assume that you would preffer a c++ example of the error, rather than c#?

Comment: Overall C++ code is preferable since the API is native itself.

Comment: long time no see :/ ended up testing a c++ player and comparing it to the c# managed player and we had multiple machines where c++ player doesnt have a rising memory, while c# player memory keeps going upwards slowly... not sure what to think. we will be trying to do the topology building in c++ and calling that from a c# wrapper.